# Can PDU mode SMS be received by any cell phone properly?

Tags: c#, windows

I want to send SMS in any Indian Language (Gujarati, Kannada, Tamil) in PDU format.

If I send SMS using these languages in any cell phone – even if the phone is not supporting any language, but I am using PDU mode – is it possible to receive that particular SMS in a readable format?

Any idea about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SMPP v3.4 does support UCS-2 encoding, so you can send chars of literally any language you want

Comment: thanks for support but all handset can see that sms.I mean is it readable format.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot get what you're talking about

Comment: assume i have any Nokia phone which support only English Language now if i sent sms in French or chines language so my Nokia phone can read it properly or it shows junk character.I want such mechanism using that every phone can receive any language sms.